# change the path of input in exec() PHP

Tags: php, cmd, exec, dirname

I want that the path from which the file is uploaded `C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cmd` is coming from 
`dirname(__FILE__)`, but when i do that the script throws an error.

Working code

```
exec( dirname(__FILE__)."\\xyz.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cmd\\blue.png D:\\1.png\", $output);
```

But I want:

```
exec( dirname(__FILE__)."\\xyz.exe" dirname(__FILE__)."\\blue.png D:\\1.png\", $output);
```

Comment: try `__DIR__` instead of `dirname()`

Comment: You need to share the error it throws.

Answer (score 1):

Why not chdir before executing all:

```
$imagename = 'blue.png';
$command = 'chdir ' . __DIR__ . '; xyz.exe ' . $imagename . ' D:\\1.png\\ ';
exec( $command, $output);
```

Comment: by using chdir image cannot save to 'D:\\1.png\\' path it save in DIR path from where the image is upload

Comment: thanks for help one more help how to use string instead of blue.png i.e if i want to give image name dynamically using file uploader
$command = 'chdir ' . __DIR__ . '; xyz.exe ' .$file_name. '1.png';

Comment: it cannot work 'chdir' contain no directory from where the file upload